# How to convert insertion sort to an O(n logn) algorithm?

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

I wrote the following function which counts repeating instances of strings while creating a sorted sequence of strings. However it was slow, then I realized that is O(n^2). So I would like to make it O(n logn) but I don't know how to proceed. Are there any known methods for converting such n^2 algorithm to nlogn? How should one convert it?

```
void insert (struct listNode **ptr, char *value) {
    struct listNode *newPtr;
    int cmp;

    // find a place to instert node to LL
    while(*ptr){
        // Comparision to detect & remove duplicates nodes

        cmp = strcmp(value, (*ptr)->data);
        // duplicate
        if(cmp == 0){
            (*ptr)->occurrence++;
            return; 
        }
        // the point where i need to add the node
        if(cmp < 0) 
            break;

        ptr = &(*ptr)->next;
    }

    // now here *ptr points to the pointer that i want to change
    // it can be NULL, if we are at the end of the LL

    newPtr = malloc(sizeof *newPtr);
    if(!newPtr)
        return;

    newPtr->data = strdup(value);
    newPtr->occurrence = 1;

    if(newPtr->data == NULL){
        free(newPtr);
        return;     
    }

    // here we are connecting our brand new node to the LL
    newPtr->next = *ptr;
    *ptr = newPtr;
}

struct listNode {
    char *data;
    struct listNode *next;
    int occurrence;
};
```

Comment: Use a different algorithm. There are many other sorting algorithms at O(n log n). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are there any known methods for converting such `n`<sup>2</sup> algorithm to `n`*log`n`?

In situations when one of the two `n`s that you multiply comes from accessing a linear data structure, such as your linked list, you can improve to `n`*log`n` by moving to a faster data structure, such as a balanced binary tree.

This would translate into replacing the `while` loop search, which is linear, with a search in a binary tree, which is log`n`.

Comment: You are suggesting that I should just integrate the methodology implemented in  http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson18.html to my code. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: @user4751640 That page describes a binary tree, so it's a good first approximation. However, the tree may be unbalanced, bringing you back to O(n^2) performance if your sequence is in ascending or descending order (so all nodes will be added only on the left or only on the right, making the tree behave like a linked list). There are techniques for keeping your tree balanced - here is a very popular one: [RB-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree).

Answer (score 1):

If I read it correctly, you are using insertion sort, which has a complexity of O(n^2). However, if you switch to binary search in your finding phase (the while loop), you may be able to do it in O(nlogn).

Answer (score 0):

Insertion sort is a individual sorting technique. If you `convert(according complexity)` this, it will be another type of sorting technique.
I think this `link` [Sorting Algorithm](https://www.cpp.edu/~ftang/courses/CS241/notes/sorting.htm) is helpful for you to `find different type complexity of sorting technique`.

Answer (score 0):

Insertion sort has worst-case time O(N<sup>2</sup>).
I suggest to use a different algorithm having Theta(n lg n) time complexity such as merge sort instead of trying to change the time complexity of a *stable* algorithm.

Let's get some useful informations that maybe will help people know how to reduce time complexity of such a problem to Theta(n lg n).

Generally, you can use divide and conquer technique in order to decrease a sorting problem's time complexity to Theta(n lg n).

Let's understand this algorithm design paradigm together.

**Divide-and-Conquer**

The idea is that if you divide an enemy into small pieces, each piece, and hence the enemy, can be conquered. When applied to computer problems divide-and-conquer involves three steps.

- Divide the problem into sub-problems that are similar to the original but smaller in size
- Conquer the sub-problems by solving them recursively.
  If they are small enough, just solve them in a straightforward manner.
- Combine the solutions to create a solution to the original problem

**Using Divide-and-Conquer for Sorting**

This turns out to be so easy that it is perhaps surprising that it is asymptotically optimal. The key observation is that merging two sorted lists is fast (the time is linear in the size of the list). The steps are

- Divide (with stopping condition):
  If S has zero or one element, simply return S since it is already sorted.
  Otherwise S has n≥2 elements: Move the first ⌈n/2⌉ elements of S into S1 and the remaining ⌊n/2⌋ elements into S2.
- Solve recursively: Recursively sort each of the two subsequences.
- Combine: Merge the two (now sorted) subsequences back into S

**Running time T(n) of Merge Sort**

- **Divide:** computing the middle takes Theta(1)
- **Conquer:** solving 2 subproblems takes 2T(n/2)
- **Combine:** merging n elements takes Theta(n)
  Total:

  T(n) = Theta(1)             if n = 1
  T(n) = 2T(n/2) + Theta(n)   if n > 1

  => T(n) = Theta(n lg n)

[image]

For more informations and examples, check this [link](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Eeppstein/161/960118.html).

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you don't proceed by reworking an existing algorithm to improve its complexity, you design it to be efficient from the beginning. Anyway, let us play this game.

The working principle of the algorithm is to keep a list of the `N` first elements, arranged in sorted order, and to incorporate the remaining elements one by one. This approach suffers from the high cost of the insertions, that involve a linear search through the sorted list, `O(N)`, giving a total of `O(N²)` for the sort.

As is well known, searching through a sorted list can be done much more efficiently in time `O(Log(N))` by binary search. Unfortunately, this works with an array (for random accesses), but an array takes `O(N)` time for insertions. The solution to this dilemma was found long ago to be the (balanced) binary tree data structure, which allows both fast searches and fast insertions.

Another, less obvious way to look at the problem, is to try and reduce the number of insertion passes. Indeed, if you insert several elements at a time, and have those elements in sorted order, the insertions can be done in a single pass: this is called a merge operation.

As detailed by @ChakerMallek, if you split the list in two halves, sort them separately, the global sort amounts to a merge, done in time `O(N)`. The sorting of the two sub-lists can be done recursively, leading to the well-known MergeSort, quite appropriate for the linked-list representation and optimally efficient. It can even be adapted to be faster on nearly sorted lists.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I think you can do this, the main idea in insertion sort is to find the correct position to add the new element.

to find the correct position we have to way:

1. linear search
2. binary search

if you used binary search the total complexity will be n(log n)

Comment: Once you found the correct position for the current value, just *how* do you proceed?